# Optimiser for excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel

I'm a mechanical engineer, and I have developed a pretty cool spreadsheet that I use to size some steel members for lifting beams. The set back is that I need to do some trial and error in the selection of the member until I get one that gets as close to the allowable limits as possible.
What I'm hoping to improve on is to develop a function that based upon a length and weight variable that I enter, the program runs a loop and automatically selects the best member size(s) based upon a list of the members and their physical properties. Is this possible?

Comment: I know it exists, it must exist, but I've yet to find the limit of what Excel can do.  So yes. It's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, depending on the complexity, either a simple search through parameters (less than, more than etc) might bring you the answer. You can do it quite easily via Pandas library. Just load up the excel as pandas DataFrame ([pandas.read_excel()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)), which then will allow you to perform the searches on that DataFrame object.

If you want to run some optimization algo, you should look into SciPy's [optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html) to get what you're looking for based on the input data (it handles unconstrained and constrained functions).

Of course, the question you've stated is quite general, so I only pointed the direction. More info would be better.